# Galaxy S2 Philz Touch 5 Bootloop

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, recovery-mode, data-recovery, boot-loop

My girlfriend's phone is a Galaxy S2. The battery was crap and the phone started bootlooping. We've replaced the battery but it is still happening. I can get into recovery mode, but I don't know anything about Flashing Roms. We're trying to avoid Factory Reseting the phone, in order to save the data. I have tried wiping the various caches. Is there anything I can do? The recovery screen also has a Philz Touch 5 menu, I believe the phone is rooted (although honestly I know nothing about it, I never rooted my phone).

Comment: Philz recovery is a custom recovery, so something has definitely been done with the phone. You could restore to stock (but that will wipe the phone), or try and flash a custom ROM over the existing one (dirty flash) and see if it boots and retains data. For how to flash head to XDA developers for the EXACT device she has (the specific type of S2) and you download a zip of the ROM and in Philz "install zip" and that's about it.

Comment: You might wish to see our [boot-loop tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/boot-loop/info) for some first-aid. Though most of it you probably already tried, it still might contain something additional (like the safe-mode hints).

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely rooted..
So it's better to completely wipe the phone..

But as you need your data, you can try and run it in safe mode.

As soon as you boot your phone , press down the volume down button, keep holding until you reach the lock screen. then press the safe mode button on bottom left..

http://www.tested.com/tech/android/3071-how-to-use-androids-safe-mode-to-save-a-phone-from-boot-loops/

In case you are flashing the best rom for Galaxy s2 is the Pound rom(Unsung Hero) or Cyanogenmod(popular)..